# Can't manually connect HC-05 master to slave

Tags: bluetooth, hc-05

Using [this](http://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-to-configure-pair-two-hc-05-bluetooth-module-master-slave-commands/) as a tutorial, I've tried to connect the master Bluetooth module from my Nano to the slave module in my Mega. After following the steps in the tutorial, when I enter the command to my serial monitor:

```
AT+BIND=98d3,31,30690
```

I receive:

```
ERROR:(7)
```

After looking up the error, I only get results for ERROR:(0)

Does anyone know what the error means or how to fix it?

Comment: [Error Codes and their definitions](http://www.galaxysofts.com/new/bluetooth-error-codes/)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Apparently, both of my modules were at `9600` baud rate when the optimal rate is of `38400`. I had to use `AT+ORGL` in command mode to reset both slave and master. Afterwards I was able to connect them manually.

So apparently `ERROR:(7)` represents a failed connection? Just don't forget to make sure everything is exactly like the tutorial that's teaching you.

Comment: Error 7 is "Bluetooth address LAP is too long" Other Error Codes are [here](http://www.galaxysofts.com/new/bluetooth-error-codes/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add zeros to your address.
For example my address of slave is "FCA8:A7:A134"
So command to bind it to master will be "AT+BIND=FCA8,7A,00A134"
XXXX:XX:XXXXXX